# Session gets null in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

My application has a *Session Fixation Vulnerability*. To fix that vulnerability, I am changing the session id after login.

I am having below web pages in different folders Master and Transaction.

`~/Master/Login.aspx` : After the credentials validated, I am setting

```
Response.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"].Value ="xyz";
Session["ASPFIXATION"] = "xyz"
```

and redirect to ~/Master/Home.aspx

`~/Master/Home.aspx` : In this page, I am checking the session value with the cookie value on page load event.

```
string cookie_value = string.Empty;
string session_value = string.Empty;
if (Request.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"] != null)
    cookie_value = Request.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"].Value;
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPFIXATION"] != null)
    session_value = HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPFIXATION"].ToString();
if (cookie_value != g_SessionFix)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = null;
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
    if (Request.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"] != null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"].Value = null;
        Response.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/Master/Login.aspx", false);
}
```

Here the Session has the value and it is validated.

`~/Transaction/Report.aspx` : If i redirect to this page and have to check the same session and cookie value logic in this page load. But here the value of `HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPFIXATION"]` is `null` and value of `HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession` also `true`

Comment: can you please share you code here. Need more information to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reassign the value after reading the values, sometimes it clears the values after reading from the session:

```
    if (Request.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"] != null)
    {
        cookie_value = Request.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"].Value;
        Request.Cookies["ASPFIXATION"].Value = cookie_value;
    }

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPFIXATION"] != null)
    {
        session_value = HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPFIXATION"].ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPFIXATION"] = session_value;
    }
```

If it still doesn't work for you then you have one other option to do it,
if your session data is not confidential then try to pass it in query string and on page redirection retrieve this value.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Master/Login.aspx?data=" + session_value +");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I can navigate to many pages within the Master folder. But if i am navigating to different folder like Transaction, all the session object gets null value